# Using VBA to indent parent child columns

Tags: excel, vba

I have the table below and need help indenting parent child relationships. The root node starts at 0 and can traverse 1000+ levels deep as can the child relationships.

How do i achieve this in VBA?

```
CPackName      CPackID      PPackID      PName      ParentID      PDATA 
Artifacts      1            1            AC         0             297
Template       1            1            AC         0             281
WA             1            1            AC         0             361
Alisha         361          361          WA         1             611 
Damian         361          361          WA         1             480
ABC            297          297          Artifacts  1             
DEF            297          297          Artifacts  1
```

I would like to show this in columns as below.

[image]

Comment: What are you expecting this to look like?  A vertical list with indentation of 1000+ doesn't sound very useful.

Comment: @RBarryYoung - I updated my post with a screenshot of what i would like it to look like.

Comment: Do you really rely on Excel? What about MS Access to store the data? It will help you to extract (select) the data.

Comment: @Markus - It isn't so much the selection of data. It's the presentation of it. Since Excel is used for everything we do and Access is not distributed, i am working within the boundaries of what is available.

Comment: How many rows in your list?

Comment: And what version of excel?

Comment: @RBarryYoung - At the moment, approximately 10,000. I expect this to grow to 50,000 or more. Excel 2010.

Comment: @Markus makes a very good point, though in the wrong place: please explain what your columns mean, and how your tree structure is related to them.  The column names are unclear/misleading and their values make their use ambiguous.

Comment: @RBarryYoung - CPackName is the name of the record. CPackID is the pack it belongs to. PPackID is the id of the pack. PName is the name of the pack. ParentID is the parent the pack belongs to.  PDATA is the relationship between CPackID and PDATA

Comment: The column PDATA1 does not exist (RBarryOld will realize this when I made this post). Does the data matches to your image? (There is only one `ParentID` that maches the `PPackID`.

Comment: @Markus - Sorry my mistake. I have updated it. Yes it does match.

Comment: Ok, the algorithm for this is pretty simple, but the actual vba is complicated because of the excel object model interactions.  Give me a bit to put it together.

Comment: So to find the parent row of the current row, you have find the row whose PDATA is the same as the current row's CPackID?  Is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following Excel-VBA module works for me.

```
Option Explicit

Type Tree_Node          ' note: and IDX of zero means that it does not exist.
    Idx As Long         'The array index of the original source record
    ParentIdx As Long   'The array index of the parent of this node
    Depth As Long       'The number of parent nodes above this node
    OutRow As Long      'The row offset this node should appear at
    Flink As Long       'next sibling of this node
    ChildCount As Long  'number of children found so far
    HeadIdx As Long     'First child node of this parent-node
    TailIdx As Long     'Last child node of this parent node
End Type
Private nod() As Tree_Node

Private maxDepth As Long

' Formats Record/Pack data into indented records.
'
'Parameters:
'   InputRange      - The source range that contains the record/pack data.
'                    (should NOT include the column headers)
'   FirstOutputCell - The top-left cell that the output data will be written to.
'                    All cells below or to the right of this may be overwritten.
'
Sub OutputIndentedRecords(InputRange As Range, FirstOutputCell As Range)
    ' Get all of the input data into a variant array
    Dim src As Variant
    src = InputRange
    Dim srcRows As Long
    srcRows = UBound(src, 1)
    ' source range column offsets
    Const CPackName = 1
    Const PPackID = 3
    Const PDATA = 6

    Dim PDataIdxs As New Collection 'collection to index the PDATA values
    ReDim nod(srcRows)  'array to hold the Tree Nodes representing each record

    '   make the zero entry the ultimate root, with no parent
    nod(0).ParentIdx = -1
    PDataIdxs.Add 0, "1"

    '   For each record in the source range, make a Tree_Node to represent it
    '(NOTE: This algorithm assumes that the parent always appears before its children
    '       in the source range.)
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    For i = 1 To srcRows
        'is there a record here?
        If src(i, CPackName) <> "" Then
            ' Yes, so fill in the tree node
            With nod(i)

                .Idx = i
                ' Get the parent index
                .ParentIdx = PDataIdxs(CStr(src(i, PPackID)))
                ' add this node to the Parents child list
                With nod(.ParentIdx)
                    If .TailIdx <> 0 Then       'if theres already a child
                        nod(.TailIdx).Flink = i 'point it to us
                    Else                        'otherwise
                        .HeadIdx = i            'we are the head of the child list
                    End If
                    .TailIdx = i                'we are the new tail
                    .ChildCount = .ChildCount + 1
                End With

                ' Is it a potential Parent?
                If src(i, PDATA) <> "" Then
                    'yes, so flag it and index its PDATA value
                    PDataIdxs.Add i, CStr(src(i, PDATA))
                End If

            End With
        End If
    Next i

    ' Traverse the Tree structure, filling in Depth and Output row number
    Dim curRow As Long
    curRow = 1
    maxDepth = 0

    TraverseTreeDepthFirst 0, 1, curRow

    ' Make an output array and fill it in
    Dim out() As Variant
    ReDim out(curRow - 2, maxDepth - 2)
    For i = 1 To srcRows
        With nod(i)
            out(.OutRow - 2, .Depth - 2) = src(.Idx, CPackName)
        End With
    Next i

    'Make an output range to hold the array
    Dim wsOut As Worksheet, rngOut As Range
    Set wsOut = FirstOutputCell.Worksheet
    Set rngOut = wsOut.Range(FirstOutputCell, _
                            wsOut.Cells(FirstOutputCell.Row + curRow - 2, _
                                        FirstOutputCell.Column + maxDepth - 2))
    ' write out the output array
    rngOut = out
End Sub

' Depth-first tree traversal, filling in the node depth and row number
Sub TraverseTreeDepthFirst(ByVal cur As Long, ByVal curDepth As Long, ByRef curRow As Long)
    With nod(cur)

        ' set values of the current node
        .Depth = curDepth
        .OutRow = curRow
        curRow = curRow + 1
        If curDepth > maxDepth Then maxDepth = curDepth

        ' Traverse any children first
        If .HeadIdx > 0 Then
            TraverseTreeDepthFirst .HeadIdx, curDepth + 1, curRow
        End If

        ' Move to next sibling
        If .Flink > 0 Then
            TraverseTreeDepthFirst .Flink, curDepth, curRow
        End If
    End With

End Sub
```

Just call `OutputIndentedRecords` passing in the range of the source data and the first cell of the output range.

Let me know if you have any questions.

---

Here's how to setup a button to call this subroutine:

First, add the following VBA code to your subject worksheet's code module:

```
Sub CallOutputIndent()

    Dim src As Range
    Set src = Selection

    OutputIndentedRecords src, Worksheets("OutputWs").Cells(2, 2)

End Sub
```

Change the Worksheet name above from "OutputWs" to whatever you output worksheet is named.  also change the (2,2) to whatever the first output cell on that worksheet should be.

Next, go to your source worksheet and from the "Insert" menu, add a button/rectangular shape.  Right-click it and pick "Assign Macro..", and then assign the `CallOutputIdent` macro to it.

To use it, just select the input range and click the button.  that should be it.

Comment: That doesn't work for me. When i attempt to run the macro, the function OutputIndentedRecords can't be called i.e. i don't see anything in the list.

Comment: You cannot call a subroutine with parameters as a plain old macro.  I will post an example of how to cal it ...

Comment: Thanks RBarryYoung. I tried that and it crashes Excel as soon as i hit the button.

Comment: It works for me, could be a spelling or name problem.  Try setting a break point on the first line and walking through it.  Or else set "Break On All Errors" from the VBA Options dialog.

Comment: I also get the error 'Method or data member not found' at the line `.IsParent = True`

Comment: Just delete that line.  It was supposed to be removed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57634/discussion-between-peanutsmonkey-and-rbarryyoung).

Comment: Is there a way to accommodate blank CPackName?

Comment: Right now it's written to interpret a blank `CPackName` as the end of the data within the source range.  Just change that condition to also check say `CPackID` for blank also.

Comment: Sorry but am out of my depths. How do i change the condition to check whether `CPackID` is blank or that a blank `CPackName` is to the end of the data source range.

Comment: @PeanutsMonkey Hmm, I should have said `PPackID` rather than `CPackID`.  You just change the line `If src(i, CPackName) <> "" Then` to `If src(i, CPackName) <> "" OR src(i,PPackID) <> "" Then`.

Comment: Thanks RBarryYoung. I tried that on the sample data and it works fine however as soon as i try on actual data, it fails. I get an invalid procedure error. Is there a way to see where it fails i.e at which record?

Comment: @PeanutsMonkey We are way beyond the original question here.  If you know how to use the VBA debugger this should be simple.  If you do not, you should goggle a tutorial online (there are many).  If you still have questions after that, you should post it as a separate question.

Comment: @RBarryYoung It also does not work on my computer (Excel 2010) it throws a cryptic error: "runtime error (9): Subscription out of range"! At least you downvoted somebody. Thanks (ironically)!