# Reading parent/child relationship from sheet

Tags: excel, vba, outline

I have an excel spreadsheet that is generated from a software I use. This spreadsheet includes a list of items (similar to a BOM) and they are arranged using Outlines (tree view).
I now want to perform some data processing using a macro and to do that I need to know the parent/child relationship of every item. Is there a function that will output the parent for each item.
thanks in advance for the support.

Comment: Offset() may work, but difficult to guess how as no data to work with. Vba may be a better choice if there are lots of relationships

Comment: VBA would be fine. Is there a function to that. I found this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.outline.parent but i didn't manage to make it work

Comment: Did you find : https://stackoverflow.com/q/49696422/4961700

Comment: What about: https://stackoverflow.com/q/24850837/4961700

Answer (score 0):

We were using an extra column for numbering each line in a layout similar to "table of contents"

like for example

```
1. heading
1.01 sub heading
1.02 sub heading 2
```

to get parent of 1.02 you can use a formula like below

```
=LEFT(F12,LEN(F12)-3)
```